# regex get a match

Tags: c#, regex

How can i get `|ADT^A05|` out of

> "MSH|^~\&|PHTADT09|ABC|DADIST00|ABC|20120425152829|rcalini1|ADT^A05|20429208851634|P|2.1|560"

I have tried this but not working

```
"|([A-Z]{3})^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})|"
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `|` and `^`, as those are special characters in a Regex.

```
@"\|([A-Z]{3})\^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})\|"
```

Or if you don't like verbatim literals:

```
"\\|([A-Z]{3})\\^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})\\|"
```

Note that verbatim literals (using `@` before the opening quote) make regexes SIGNIFICANTLY more readable (and more portable -- now you can just copy/paste that regex somewhere else). You should always use verbatim literals with regex strings unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I don't think using verbatim or not should be a matter of preference. It just creates regexes that with worse readability. I think you should explicitly discourage the use of non-verbatim strings here, and recommend using verbatim for these purposes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need Regex when there is a separator char like `|`

```
var adt = text.Split('|')[8];
```

See the definition of [HL7](http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/ParsingHL7_SettingUpVmd.html) format

> Each segment in a message is divided into composites, or fields, and the fields are separated by pipe characters ('|')

Comment: While this may or may not work for the OPs current problem, it's always worth looking at the non-regex solutions.  Many times they're easier to write, faster to execute and easier to understand later on.

Answer (score 2):

Put backslashes before certain characters: `|` and `^`.

```
\|([A-Z]{3})\^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{2})\|
```

Edit: My favorite site ever - http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Firstly, regexpal.com uses the JavaScript regex flavor. Which is a lot different from the .NET one (and much more limited). If you are using an online regex tester, you should pick the appropriate one: [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/). Secondly, the OP does not seem to use a verbatim string, in that case your backslashes need to be doubled (see ean5533's answer)

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for the info!  I'll definitely check out that site.  Perhaps I've gotten very lucky with regexpal, but it's always worked for me for .Net.

Comment: .NET can handle everything JavaScript can. But not the other way round. regexpal can't do lookbehinds. regexpal can't do balanced grouping. regexpal can't do `Singleline` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to BizTalk, Microsoft has [accelerator for HL7](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/accelerator-hl7.aspx) that will break your message into XML.  Otherwise, I would go with **L.B**'s answer and split the string directly.